# PharData offsetExists on filename prefixed with ".\"

Tags: php, gzip

I have a .tar.gz file downloaded from an external API which we have to implement. It contains images for an object.
I'm not sure how they managed to compress it this way, but the files are basically prefixed with the "current directory". It looks like this in WinRAR:
[image: WinRAR compressed files]
And like this in 7-Zip, note the .tar first level, and "." second level:
[image: 7-Zip Top level] -> [image: 7-Zip tar level] ->
[image]

When calling

```
$file = 'archive.tar.gz';
$phar = new PharData($file, FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO);
var_dump($phar->offsetGet('./12613_s_cfe3e73.jpg'));
```

I get the exception:

> Cannot access phar file entry '/12613_s_cfe3e73.jpg' in archive '{...}/archive.tar.gz'

Calling a file which does not exist, e.g.:

```
var_dump($phar->offsetGet('non-existent.jpg'));
```

Or calling it without the directory seperator, e.g.:

```
var_dump($phar->offsetGet('12613_s_cfe3e73.jpg'));
```

I get a

> Entry 12613_s_cfe3e73.jpg does not exist

Exception.

It is not possible to get the archive formatted differently. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Ended up using [Archive_Tar](https://github.com/pear/Archive_Tar). There must be something wrong in the source code of PHP, though I don't think this is the "normal" way of packaging a .tar either.
Unfortunately I'm not very good at C, but it's probably in [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/phar/util.c) ([line 1214](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/phar/util.c#L1214)) or [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/03b765173b5776c2eaa585b809efad2a46fe5708/ext/phar/phar_object.c).

This library seems to handle it just fine, using this example code:

```
$file = 'archive.tar.gz';
$zip = new Archive_Tar($file);
foreach ($zip->listContent() as $file) {
    echo $file['filename'] . '<br>';
}
```

Result:

> ./12613_s_f3b483d.jpg
>   ./12613_s_cfe3e73.jpg
>   ./1265717_s_db141dc.jpg
>   ./1265717_s_af5de56.jpg
>   ./1265717_s_b783547.jpg
>   ./1265717_s_35b11f9.jpg
>   ./1265716_s_83ef572.jpg
>   ./1265716_s_9ac2725.jpg
>   ./1265716_s_c5af3e9.jpg
>   ./1265716_s_c070da3.jpg
>   ./1265715_s_4339e8a.jpg

Note the filenames are still prefixed with "./" just like they are in WinRAR.

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting to see how bad these two APIs suck, however at least the pear extension is able to read tar archives with files containing a `./` prefix. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to using PharData, i suggest a more conservative, two-step approach, where you first decompress the gz and then unarchive all files of the tar to a target folder.

```
// decompress gz archive to get "/path/to/my.tar" file
$gz = new PharData('/path/to/my.tar.gz');
$gz->decompress(); 

// unarchive all files from the tar to the target path
$tar = new PharData('/path/to/my.tar');
$tar->extractTo('/target/path');
```

But it looks like you want to select individual files from the `tar.gz` archive directly, right?

It should work using fopen() with a StreamReader (compress.zlib or phar) and selecting the individual file. Some examples:

```
$f = fopen("compress.zlib://http://some.website.org/my.gz/file/in/the/archive", "r");
$f = fopen('phar:///path/to/my.tar.gz//file/in/archive', 'r');
$filecontent = file_get_contents('phar:///some/my.tar.gz/some/file/in/the/archive');
```

Streaming should also work, when using Iterators:

```
$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('phar:///path/to/my.tar.gz')
$rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ($rii as $splFileInfo){
    echo file_get_contents($splFileInfo->getPathname());
}
```

The downside is that you have to buffer the stream and save it to file.

Its not a direct file extraction to a target folder.

Comment: The problem is, I need, say, 20 files, but I have 50 archives. So I want to know which archives contain those files, and extract specifically those files, if possible, otherwise the entire archive and grab the ones I want, as long as I can skip the others.  
For the phar:/// method, does this need to be an absolute path, or relative to the www root? I can't seem to get it to work with the same path that "is_file('...')" would return true on.

Comment: I've used absolute paths in the examples, that's why there is a third slash. The third slash is the start of an absolute path and having that said, if you leave the slash away then you have a relative path. `phar://` works the same way as `file://`. Maybe this makes it more clear `fopen('phar://./my.tar.gz/file.txt', 'r');`. Ah, ok - you ended up using Archive_Tar. Allright. If you are sure, that this is a PHP bug, please report it.